# How to use XShmGetImage and XShmPutImage

Tags: c, x11, shared-memory

I've got this program that's really really slow. Profiling reveals the bottleneck is in XGetImage (no I can't get out of calling XGetImage in a loop). On reading up the recommended solution is to call XShmGetImage instead, but the documentation really sucks.

I'm seeking really simple example code of how to call XShmCreateImage, XShmGetImage and XShmSetImage.

Deep profiling definitely makes XGetImage the root bottleneck not XPutImage (yes I know to call XFlush to make the profiling accurate), and therefore I might conclude that the implicit call to the memory allocator is what's actually slow but there isn't a variant of XGetImage that lets me pass a preallocated XImage except for XShmGetImage. Use of the Shm functions is likely to improve yet more anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MIT-SHM documentation doesn't suck. It simply doesn't exist.

Here's a working incantation:

```
  Display *d;
  int s;
  XImage *image;
  XShmSegmentInfo shminfo;
  d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  s = DefaultScreen(d);

  image = XShmCreateImage(d, 
      DefaultVisual(d,0), // Use a correct visual. Omitted for brevity     
      24,   // Determine correct depth from the visual. Omitted for brevity
      ZPixmap, NULL, &shminfo, 100, 100); 

  shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,
      image->bytes_per_line * image->height,
      IPC_CREAT|0777);

  shminfo.shmaddr = image->data = shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0);
  shminfo.readOnly = False;

  XShmAttach(d, &shminfo);

  XShmGetImage(d,
      RootWindow(d,0),
      image,
      50,
      50,
      AllPlanes);
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *' ` on the line  `shminfo.shmaddr = image->data = shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0); `.

Comment: @AokiAhishatsu This should be a question not a comment.

Comment: My problem was that C++ needs explicit cast. Using `(char*)shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0);` works.